# Azure DevOps private build agent - 'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, azure-devops

**Problem:** For some reason our Private build agent throws the following error:

"'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command" when we try to invoke npm run build:prod

**What I've tried:**

- I tried installing webpack globally using: npm install --global
  webpack
- I tried adding webpack to the path variable
- I tried running the command 'npm run build:prod' directly on the build servrer (agent) - it works fine

**Additional info:**

- Our AzureDevops build agents run as the NetworkService user
- In AzureDevOps, I added a build task "npm" install and an additional step
  which runs "npm run build:prod"

This is the complete error message:

```
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
5.6.0
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v8.9.4 win32 x64"

; environment configs
userconfig = "E:\\vsts-agent\\aztc-agent-1\\_work\\28\\npm\\3704.npmrc"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Windows\\ServiceProfiles\\NetworkService\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = E:\vsts-agent\aztc-agent-1\_work\28\s\Src\Project\Template\Code
; HOME = C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build:prod"

> [name]@0.0.1 build:prod E:\vsts-agent\aztc-agent-1\_work\28\s\Src\Project\Template\Code
> webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress
'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Comment: Does Webpack is in package.json as dev dependency but Build Agent NODE_ENV var set to "production"?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in the end was:

1. Add Npm task of type "install"
2. **Add path to where package.json file is
   located**
3. **Add Npm task of type "custom" with working folder pointing to same folder as in step 2.** and with "Command and arguments" field set to "run build:prod"